# A recursion related issue in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops

This is the background to this question:

Background
Take any integer n greater than 1 and apply the following algorithm

1. If n is odd then n = n × 3 + 1 else n = n / 2
2. If n is equal to 1 then stop, otherwise go to step 1

The following demonstrates what happens when using a starting n of 6

6 - 3 - 10 - 5 - 16 - 8 - 4 - 2 - 1

After 8 generations of the algorithm we get to 1.
It is conjectured that for every number greater than 1 the repeated application of this algorithm will
eventually get to 1.

The question is how can I find a number that takes exactly 500 generations to reduce to 1?

The code below is my version but appearntly got some wrong logic. Could you help me correct this? Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sequence1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int start = 1;
            int flag = 0;
            int value;
            while(true){
                int temp = (start - 1) / 3;
                string sta = temp.ToString();
                    if (Int32.TryParse(sta, out value) )
                    {
                        if (((start - 1) / 3) % 2 == 1)
                        {
                            start = (start - 1) / 3;
                            flag++;
                            if (flag == 500)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            start = start * 2;
                            flag++;
                            if (flag == 500)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        start = start * 2;
                        flag++;
                        if (flag == 500)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }


            Console.WriteLine("result is {0}", start);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An `int` named `flag`? `ToString` followed by `TryParse`? Sorry, but this code is unreadable.

Comment: This is a "it doesn't work" question without details. What goes wrong, what is the error?

Comment: You mentioned recursions, but I only see loops.

Comment: I believe your 3 `if (flag == 500)` blocks are rather pointless. And you only need one `flag++` at the end, not 3 of them.

Comment: 4 upvotes for an unclear homework question?

Comment: The easy answer would be n = 2^500, but I suppose that's a bit too big...

Comment: It would be better if you first solve the problem using math, a piece of paper and pencil. Then, I believe, code will be much simpler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your question's title is *"A **recursion** related issue"*, I will give you a recursive solution.

```
int Process(int input, int maxRecursionDepth)
{
    // condition to break recursion
    if (maxRecursionDepth == 0 || input == 1)
        return input;

    if (input % 2 == 1) // odd case
        return Process(input * 3 + 1, maxRecursionDepth - 1);
    else // even case
        return Process(input / 2, maxRecursionDepth - 1);
}
```

Now to find all number in a specified range, that return 1 after exactly 500 recursions:

```
int startRange = 1, endRange = 1000;
int maxDepth = 500;

List<int> resultList = new List<int>();
for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++)
{
    if (Process(i, maxDepth) == 1)
        resultList.Add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is a part of Collatz conjecture (about recursively defined function) which has not been solved yet:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

so I think brute force is a good way out:

```
public static int GetMinNumber(int generations) {
  if (generations < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("generations");

  // Memoization will be quite good here
  // but since it takes about 1 second (on my computer) to solve the problem
  // and it's a throwaway code (all you need is a number "1979515")
  // I haven't done the memoization

  for (int result = 1; ; ++result) {
    int n = result;
    int itterations = 0;

    while (n != 1) {
      n = (n % 2) == 0 ? n / 2 : 3 * n + 1;
      itterations += 1;

      if (itterations > generations)
        break;
    }

    if (itterations == generations)
      return result;
  }
}

...

int test1 = GetMinNumber(8);   // <- 6
int test2 = GetMinNumber(500); // <- 1979515
```

Comment: Does this try all possible numbers in a brute force fashion? How long does it take?

Comment: Yes, it's a brute force; at my computer it takes about one second to find out a solution for 500

Comment: "The conjecture is that no matter what number you start with, you shall always eventually reach 1." - this problem doesn't have much to do with that conjecture still being open.

Comment: Shouldn't n = 3 * n + 1; be just 3 * n + 1; without the assignment?

Comment: @Kimi: thank you! Even if n = 3 * n + 1 doesn't spoil the matter,  of course, 3 * n + 1 is much better. I've edited the code

Comment: @Dukeling: If we have a closed formula (not a brute force version) of how many itterations do we have to do before reaching 1 (our current problem), this formula'll solve the conjecture.

Comment: _Your problem is a part of Collatz conjecture_ - No, it's about handing in homework.

Answer (score 3):

Observing the problem,

> 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
>
> In the third iteration we hit the number 10, which is smaller than 13

So instead of calculating the sequence count every time we can use a cache.

```
    static int GetMinCollatz(int maxChain)
    {
        const long number = 1000000;
       
        int minNumber = 0;
        // Temporary values
        int tempCount = 0;
        long temp = 0;
        // Cache 
        int[] sequenceCache = new int[number + 1];
        // Fill the array with -1
        for (int index = 0; index < sequenceCache.Length; index++)
        {
            sequenceCache[index] = -1;
        }
        sequenceCache[1] = 1;

        for (int index = 2; index <= number; index++)
        {
            tempCount = 0;
            temp = index;
            // If the number is repeated then we can find 
            // sequence count from cache
            while (temp != 1 && temp >= index)
            {
                if (temp % 2 == 0)
                    temp = temp / 2;
                else
                    temp = temp * 3 + 1;
                tempCount++;
            }
            sequenceCache[index] = tempCount + sequenceCache[temp];
            if (sequenceCache[index] == maxChain)
            {
                minNumber = index;
            }
        }
       
        return minNumber;
    }
```

For more details refer [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/) and [this](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-14/).

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for pointing out the error.The above function checks within the limit marked by the variable 'number'. After changing its value it works.But still for a bigger sequence we can use BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution

```
private void ReduceTo1(int input, ref int totalCount)
        {
            totalCount++;
            if (input % 2 == 0)
            {
                input = input / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                input = input * 3 + 1;
            }
            if (input != 1)
                ReduceTo1(input, ref totalCount);               

        }
```

to test

```
int desireValue = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                int totalCount = 0;
                ReduceTo1(i, ref totalCount);
                if (totalCount >= 500)
                {
                    desireValue = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
```